# JQuery Ajax Request Not appending HTML in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have no idea if this is the reason for it not displaying in IE8, however i am using Ajax to render HTML on to a div on a page, this works perfectly fine on all other browsers however not on IE8.

```
function viewClientLog(clientId) {
    $('#clientlog_dialogue .md_close').hide();
    showProgressBar();
    $('#clientlog_dialogue').show();
    $.get("ajax_requests/viewClientLog.php", {'id': clientId},
        function(data) {
            hideProgressBar();
            $('#clientlog_dialogue .md_close').show();

            var clearView = function() {
                $('#viewClientLogTable').remove();
                $('#clientlog_dialogue .md_close img').unbind("click", this);
             };
             $('#clientlog_dialogue .md_close img').bind("click", clearView);

             $('#clientlog_dialogue .md_inner').prepend(data);
        }
     );
}
```

At the moment I just get a blank HTML page. Data contains all HTML to be loaded on to the page.

Any help will be gratefully accepted

Comment: hmmm that made no change, It is still coming up with a blank page

Comment: ? what made no change?  I was asking for the html page content before the ajax request

Comment: try prepending some static html string instead of data. If it works that might be an issue with your data (ill-formed html which should be fixed, or cache issue which might be fixed by appending `'?' + Math.random()`to the url)